# Non-dynamic secondary sidebar not showing up at all

Tags: php, wordpress

**EDIT:** What's weird is even if I comment out `<?php get_footer(); ?>` it still shows up... maybe this starter theme is doing some thing behind the scenes? I should mention, I'm using the HTML5 / Starkers boilerplate theme: http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/boilerplate

**The problem:**

Having some problems adding a unique sidebar to my wordpress theme...

```
<?php get_sidebar( ‘inside’ ); ?>
```

is being called in **subpage-template.php**

This obviously is calling a non-dynamic sidebar file named **sidebar-inside.php**, which  has this inside:

```
<?php ?>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
<?php ?>
```

Simple. But for some reason, it's pulling the original **sidebar.php** still. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the correct characters for single quotes? PHP doesn't know the ‘ and ’, only the '.

Minor detail, but if the get_sidebar is exactly as you posted it in your question, that could be the problem.

(enlarged to show the difference more clearly:)

## ( ‘ ) and ( ’ ) are not ( ' )

Comment: Never hurts to have a second pair of eyes to look over it ;)